# new() keyword in the base declaration statement in C#

Tags: c#

I wonder about below new() keyword.
new() is in the base declaration statement along with IDisposable where C : DbContext and IDisposedTracker.

But I wonder about new() expression. Is this an anonymous base class declaration?

But notice a couple of arrow that I marked next to new(). Those curly brackets are owned by public class RepositoryBase, not by new().

What is new() here?

```
namespace PersonRepository
{
    public class RepositoryBase<C> : IDisposable where C : DbContext, IDisposedTracker, new()
    ->{
        public RepositoryBase()
        {
            DataContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }

        private C _DataContext;

        public virtual C DataContext
        {
            get
            {
                if (_DataContext == null || _DataContext.IsDisposed)
                {
                    _DataContext = new C();
                    AllowSerialization = true;
                    //Disable ProxyCreationDisabled to prevent the "In order to serialize the parameter, add the type to the known types collection for the operation using ServiceKnownTypeAttribute" error
                }

                return _DataContext;
            }
        }

        //partly omitted

        public void Save()
        {
            DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (DataContext != null) DataContext.Dispose();
        }
    }<-      
}
```

Comment: ***_DataContext = new C();*** is creating a **new** instance of the the class C and assigning that to the variable ***_DataContext....***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the  new() is a costraint ...it means C has to be a class and has a `EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR` ...